# How do I include my bash path when launching a .desktop file

Tags: linux, bash, path, launcher

I have a small bash script I'm using to launch a PyQt application.  The PyQt application uses python `os.system()` calls to run other commands.  I have used `gnome-desktop-item-edit` to create a launcher for my script which runs in the terminal.  Unfortunately when it executes it is not receiving any of my `.bashrc` path modifications.  How do I either:

1. cause the launcher to run in bash with my path modifications, or
2. modify the path in a more universal way so that my needed
   modifications will be reflected in the terminal created by the
   launcher?

Comment: You can modify the path in your python code with `os.environ`.

Comment: I was specifically needing to be able to access other software which has been installed and added to the path.  Looks like I just wasn't adding it to the path in the "right" way (as noted below).  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

After further research I found [a post on the super user site](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980) which explains some finer points of path editing.  Switching my path modifications to .profile instead of .bashrc did the trick.